# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tags: python, int, tuples, operand

I need to complete a task where I am given a list of names and grades for each name and I need to sort these out by highest to lowest grade. However if two names have the same grades then sort those names out in alphabetical order. This is the problem I am presented with. I am required to keep the sort function on one line.

```
a = [('Tim Jones', 54), ('Anna Smith', 56), ('Barry Thomas', 88)]
sum(sorted(a,key=lambda x: x[1]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Any idea on how this can be resolved? I've tried to work it out for many days now.

**UPDATED**

Ok thanks for helping me work out that one, however there is another scenario where I need to resolve as well.

```
a = [('Tim Jones', 'C'), ('Anna Smith', 'B'), ('Barry Thomas', 'A')]
sorted(a,key=lambda x: -x[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

So this is the current situation basically all I need to do now is organise the list so then it goes from highest grade to lowest grade.

Comment: Is the language python? You might want to add the Python tag if this is the case..

Comment: Yes it is in Python sorry about that.

Comment: Welcome to [`StackOverflow`](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for formating please visit [`Markdown Editing`](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: If you have a second question, you should post it as a new Stack Overflow question.  Don't add it as a rider to an already-answered question.  (But in this case, the traceback tells you exactly what the problem is:  What would "negative C" even _mean_?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's note that `sorted()` will return a copy of your original list, but sorted:

```
>>> a = [('Tim Jones', 54), ('Anna Smith', 56), ('Barry Thomas', 88)]
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x: x[1])
[('Tim Jones', 54), ('Anna Smith', 56), ('Barry Thomas', 88)]
```

Python itself will fail when attempting to sum these three tuples, because it doesn't really have any clear meaning.

```
('Tim Jones', 54)
('Anna Smith', 56)
('Barry Thomas', 88)
```

Answer (score 2):

The sorted() function return a tuple list. So you can't sum them up because sum() suppose to receive a sequence of numerics.

The second one is because you have a minus (-) before the x[1] while x[1] is a string. You can't have a negative string.

```
>>> a = [('Tim Jones', 'C'), ('Anna Smith', 'B'), ('Barry Thomas', 'A')]
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x: x[1])
```

If you wanna sort those names out in alphabetical order when grades are the same, then use tuple (x[1],x[0]) as the sorted key.

```
>>> a = [('Tim Jones', 54), ('Anna Smith', 56), ('Barry Thomas', 88),('Array Thomas', 88)]
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))
[('Tim Jones', 54), ('Anna Smith', 56), ('Array Thomas', 88), ('Barry Thomas', 88)]
```