# Variable in discord.py comes back as tuple and can't be used with integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot that has a counter that isnt working because a variable that I have defined comes back as a tuple even tho i have put it as a variable.

I have already tried making it a list but it still doesnt work because a list cannot be used with an integer.

```
gayrate = 00
if message.author == client.user:
    return      
if message.content.startswith('?gayrate'): 
    mssg = "Scanning....".format(message)
    await message.channel.send(mssg)
    if "a" in message.author.display_name:
        gayrate += gayrate, 1
    elif "b" in message.author.display_name:
        gayrate += gayrate, 2
    elif "c" in message.author.display_name:
        gayrate += gayrate, 3
```

I expected it to work just fine and the counter which is the simplest part to work properly.
but what I do get is an error message that says

```
>Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 16, in on_message
    gayrate += gayrate, 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Please - format your code properly - just paste the code as it is on your program editor, select it, and click on the `{}` formatting button. No need to quote line by line (besides what, the indentation is broken)

Comment: `gayrate += gayrate, 1` Can you explain in plain English what you are expecting this to do? Give an example of the value of `gayrate` before the operation, and the result you expect afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the varialbe that "cames as tuple" - you created the tuples by writting:

```
gayrate += gayrate, 1
```

I suppose your intention is just to add 1 to the `gayrate` variable -  then it is just:

```
gayrate += 1
```

in your code:

```
gayrate += gayrate, 1
```

the `,` is what transform the left-hand-side of your line in  a tuple, as parenthesis for tuples can be omitted where there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are a datatype in python. The structure looks like this `(VAR1, VAR2, ... VARn)`

The variable `gayrate` is initialized as an `integer`. However, you append the tuple `(gayrate, 1)` to that integer, which is illegal in python.

Change this line of code

```
gayrate += gayrate, 1
```

to this:

```
gayrate += gayrate + 1
```

Also, I'm not sure what this code is intended to do, but there might be a logic error in the code `gayrate += gayrate + 1`. This code basically means `gayrate = gayrate + gayrate + 1`. If you only want `gayrate = gayrate + 1`, then you would do `gayrate +=1`

Answer (score -2):

I am not great at Python plugins, but I think this [unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028833/unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-tuple) might have the answer for you